# How to consume WCF in console app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a console app and WCF service app in a solution.  I'd like to call the WCF app from the console app.  I added a service reference to the console app project and tried to reference the service but its namespace is not found.  I'm using VS 2010.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's just the stock console app and WCF service you get in vs.net.  I haven't modified them.

Comment: What is the reference namespace you gave the service? Try adding this:
using %PROJECTNAME%.NAMESPACE_OF_WEBSERVICE
Then, you should have SomethingSomethingClient myWebClient = new SomethingSomethingClient();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a Service Reference, it's not the same as an Assembly Reference.

When you can add a Service Reference, you don't necessarily know the inner details of the service.  In many cases it won't be your service, it will be another company's.  A service reference just defines the contracts.

So you won't find your service using the namespaces or objects you declared on the service side.  Rather, your client is actually defining client-side objects of its own based on the contracts.  When you added the reference, you could choose the namespace to add it to.

In Visual Studio, click on your client project in the Solution Explorer and enable the "Show All Files" option.  Then you should be able to navigate through the Service Reference and find the hidden files auto-generated the by the Add Service Reference wizard.  You will see which namespace it's declared in by inspecting those files.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the xsd files?  Those are called Service1, just like the namespace.  But I still get no intellisense on that.

Comment: Added an image to illustrate what I'm talking about.  Service references create a Reference.cs file which is where the client-side classes reside.

Comment: Checked in Reference.cs.  Nothing in there but comments.

Comment: How are you adding the reference?  Do you right-click on your console project, click Add Service Reference, click "Discover" and it finds your service from your other project?  At the bottom there should be a "Namespace" text box where you can tell it which namespace to create the client proxy in.  When you finish the wizard it should create the Reference.cs file with code in it.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it.  As another test, I started with a fresh console app, added a WCF project then added the reference to the console app.  All the intellisense is there.  So it is something about my current app that is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the reference and re-adding it?  Or right clicking on the service reference and choosing "Update Service Reference"?  It shouldn't break anything to re-add it.  As you update and add new functionality to your service you will most likely want to use the "Update Service Reference" function a lot.  If it still doesn't work maybe it's a problem in the service project.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about console applications versus other application types when it comes to web service consumption.

See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Answer (score 0):

Rececntly me too face the same problem.  I did the following steps.
1) Open Reference.cs file
2) Your error may look like below error

```
Error   3   The type name 'ServiceReference1' does not exist in the type 'LongOperationClient.ServiceReference1.LongOperationClient'
```

Now in Reference.cs file ( which is autogenerated ) delete 'NamespaceOfProject.serviceReference1'

3) save and build
It worked for me.
Regards,
Hemant